# How to delete emails from sent items that bounced in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I have a list of email addresses in excel which bounced, is there a way to compare this list to sent item emails and delete them all at once.

Eg: 250 emails sent and 200 successful, 50 bounced, then I extracted email addresses from Thunderbird inbox bounced messages, want to delete these 50 emails from sent items.

Any help would be appreciated.